# React js createRef() show typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx-react

some typescript warning 
i use `typescript@3.5.2` `react@16.8` `mobx-react@6` `mobx@5`

child functional Component

```
import { observer as HooksObserver } from 'mobx-react-lite';
const TicketForm: React.FC<any> = (props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        returnDataToParentComp: () => {
            console.log('hello')
        }
    }));
return <div></div>
}
export default HooksObserver(TicketForm,{forwardRef:true})
```

parent class Component

```
export default class ParentComp extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    formRef: React.RefObject<typeof TicketForm>;
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.formRef = createRef<typeof TicketForm>();
    }
    buttonClick = () => {
        console.log(this.formRef.current!.returnDataToParentComp);
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TicketForm ref={this.formRef} />
                <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>click me </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

show

> error:returnDataToParentComp undefined `“MemoExoticComponent<ForwardRefExoticComponent<TicketFormStatelessProps & RefAttributes<{}>>>”`

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useImperativeHandle` exists within the scope of the component and as such, the resulting object cannot be inferred to the outside scope automatically. You have to define an interface that describes it separately and supply it somewhere to the chain.

Something for the inspiration:

https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-hooks-in-typescript-88fce7001d0d#6a30

I really advise you to avoid using imperative handles. They should be considered as a last resort when you are out of options. In your case, it seems you can get away with a simple prop.

Comment: I still don't understand, in my case the click event is triggered in the parent component, is there any other way to get the data of the child component?

Comment: There are so many resources on the question "react pass data from child to parent", just google. For example: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Comment: I have tried other resolution before, but  `Ref` is better in my project. Thanks for your help, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) needs to be used in conjunction with [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

```
const TicketForm: React.FC<any> = React.forwardRef(
  (props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      returnDataToParentComp: () => {
        console.log('hello')
      }
    }));
    return <div></div>;
  }
);
```

Comment: I updated my code,I replaced `React. ForwardRef ` with `HooksObserver(TicketForm,{forwardRef:true})`